# Let $f:A\to B$ be a function. Show that $f^{-1}(f(A))=A$

Tags: solution-verification

I am taking a basic course on proof and trying some questions on relations and functions
I am trying from the very basic please understand my poor proving skills :(
I believe I have to use the definition of the image and the inverse image of f to prove

Proof) I want to show $f^{-1}(f(A))=A$

($\Rightarrow$) I want to show $f^{-1}(f(A))\subseteq A$. By definition, $f(A)=\{f(x):x\in A\}$.  By definition, $f^{-1}(f(A))=\{x\in A:f(x)\in f(A)\}\subseteq A$

($\Leftarrow$) I want to show $A\subseteq f^{-1}(f(A))$. Pick an arbitrary $x\in A$, I want to show $x\in f^{-1}(f(A))$.
$\forall x\in A,\exists!f(x)\in D\subseteq B$ call $D=f(A)$.
$f(x)\in f(A)$ by definition, $f^{-1}(f(A))=\{x\in A:f(x)\in f(A)\}$
therefore $x\in f^{-1}(f(A))$ and $A\subseteq f^{-1}(f(A))$

Comment: What you want to show is not true. Consider $f : [-1,  1] \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x) = x^2$. We have $f([0,1]) = [0,1]$. But $f^{-1}(f([0,1])) = f^{-1}([0,1]) = [-1, 1]$.

Comment: @CharlesHudgins To match the problem, $A$ would need to be the domain of $f$, so you'd have to have $A = [-1,1]$.

Comment: @BrianMoehring I missed that $A$ had to be the domain. You're right. In that case the statement is true.

Comment: Thank you so much for editing my question It is my first time using latex I will try harder to make it neat :)

Comment: It looks good. Proving that the preimage of the image is the domain is more or less a definition check. There isn't much to it.

Comment: Thank you so much guys! :)